# from package import * - strategy to avoid importing everything in python

Tags: python, import, package, pyqt5, strategy-pattern

I know that it is not a good idea to use the `from package import *` syntax in python to import everything from a package. I want a strategy to avoid importing everything, just those items that are required.
For example, below is some code - how would I go about finding which parts of the `PyQt5.Qt` package I should import, rather than * ?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text, obj):
        super(MyLabel, self).__init__(text, obj)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.setText('Left')
        if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.setText('Right')

# Creating the main window
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Sample QTWidget App'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 150
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.label = MyLabel("Click-Me", self)
        self.label.setGeometry(150, 50, 100, 20)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If a am not mistaken, you can just use the syntax `import PyQt5.Qt as pqt`

Comment: While it's true that wildcard imports are generally discouraged, that is not an absolute rule, and, as always, the choice depends on the context. Also, remember that Qt: 1. Qt programs are generally intended to be running for long time (minutes, or even months), and their startup time might not be that essential; 2. a medium-complexity program probably will use lots (hundreds) of Qt classes, either explicitly or implicitly (with some classes using many due to inheritance or for built-in requirements), so being too selective about imports may be not that beneficial as one would believe.

Comment: Remember that most systems nowadays use SSD drives, making loading the whole Qt a matter of instants. Also: the [Qt](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qt/qt-module.html) module of PyQt actually loads the *whole* Qt framework (including optional modules), so doing two imports as you did above is useless (by the way, the `Qt` module has been removed in PyQt6). And consider that if you're targeting Linux, there's a high chance that the Qt libraries are already loaded due to other applications or even the window manager (assuming that you're using the *system* Qt).

Comment: Thank-you for your comments. I see there are cases for and against ```from PyQt5.Qt import *``` However, I would still like to know how to find the sub-package required. If I remove  ```from PyQt5.Qt import *``` I get ```    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
NameError: name 'Qt' is not defined``` - but that does not help me know which sub-package to import?

Comment: @ChrisBon Look for the docs of what you're using: in every page of a Qt object you'll always find from which module the object comes from: see the `qmake` section in the summary, or just see the top of the page, which lists the hierarchy (i.e.: [QPushButton](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html) shows `Qt 5.15 > Qt Widgets > C++ Classes > QPushButton`, meaning that it's part of `QtWidgets`. Everytime you see a `Qt.Something` (note the capitalization) it's usually part of the [`Qt` namespace](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html) (which is part of QtCore): it would normally be `QtCore.Qt.LeftButton`.

Comment: This might lead to some confusion: if you use `from PyQt5 import Qt`, then `Qt.LeftButton` would actually be `Qt.Qt.LeftButton`. It's probably one of the reasons for which that module was removed in PyQt6, along with the fact that it actually loads ***all*** installed Qt modules, including the optional ones installed afterwards; this is an important aspect to consider: for instance, you may have installed things like QtPrintSupport, QtCharts, or even the QtWebEngine modules (which includes full web browser capabilities), leading to 80-90MB of RAM even if you just need a couple of buttons.

Comment: For small apps (especially if fast loading is required), you'd normally import specific classes (i.e. `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, etc`). Otherwise it's a matter of choice: either use module wildcards (`from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *`) or import the module namespace (`from PyQt5 import QtWidgets`). The difference in loading times is usually negligible for a decent computer (the former takes less than 2s on first startup on my 12yo PC with SSD, and it's usually cached after that), otherwise is a matter of name length and readability (so, if you use the `as` keyword, do it wisely).

Comment: @musicamante - Wow, thanks for all that info. My projects are not that time/memory critical but it looks like I should be moving to PyQt6 for future work.